# Vagrant/homestead: too many arguments

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I´m installing vagrant+homestead for a new laravel project.

When I write the command 'vagrant up' to the terminal, there is an error msg: 'Check your Homestead.yaml (or Homestead.json) file, the path to your private key does not exist.'

At first, according to the video tutorial, I tried to solve it with: 'ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa'.
The error msg changed to: 'Saving key "/home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory'

Then I found out, it could work when creating a folder (c:/users/havon/.ssh) for adding the path: 'c:/users/havon/.ssh/id_rsa' at the end of the command.
It is not. The error msg: 'too many arguments'.

Now it looks like this: ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa "c:/users/havon/.ssh/id_rsa"
And it doesnt work. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve it with: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"`.

Then it ask you for path with a msg:
Enter file in which to save the key `(c:/users/havon/.ssh/id_rsa)`:

This works for me.